# Lead validity should only be 10 business days

Tags: mysql

I'm currently dealing with leads and I need to filter the leads by using a mysql code. Leads should expire in 10 business days from the entry date. I know how to write the code for 10 days but I don't know how to make it 10 business days.

Comment: Search SO for _mysql business days_ and you'll find lots of related answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with five business days per week (ie, no messing about with holidays), ten business days is *always* fourteen actual days:

```
 M  T  W  T  F  S  S
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

Note how every day-of month in the third/fourth week is exactly fourteen greater than that in the first/second week, and there's always exactly two weekends between them.

So just use 14.

That wouldn't always work for values that *aren't* a multiple of five but, luckily, your case is.

If you want a number of business days that's not a multiple of five, or if you want to handle arbitrary holidays, you'll probably have to code up a user defined function.